# SQL Join With Limit Range

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

I'm trying to add a limit range to my sql join statement so I can do pagination of my records, but when I enter in the limit range to my statement I'm getting nothing returned.  With the limit range taken out it all works fine.

Here is what I have:

```
$sql= "SELECT R.id,companyName,membershipID,addressID,city,logo,descriptionShort FROM yt_Business_RegInfo R
    INNER JOIN yt_Business_Seasons S
    ON R.id = S.busID AND S.deleted = '0'
    INNER JOIN yt_Business_Address A
    ON R.addressID = A.id
    INNER JOIN yt_Business_Membership M
    ON R.membershipID = M.id AND M.approved = 1
    WHERE R.deleted = '0'
    ORDER BY R.companyName ASC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are the values of $start and $limit? Can you change it to `limit 10 offset 0` to test if it returns anything?

Comment: $limit=10 and $start is just a variable whose value is based on the page.  I tried putting in limit 0, 10 but I get the same results.

Comment: Ok I got this figured out.  I had another sql statement further down my page that didn't like something, so I included it all in my one sql join statement.  The limit above now works.

Answer (score 2):

That should be:

```
LIMIT $start, $howMany
```

If `($howMany <= 0)` or `($start > number of rows returned without LIMIT)` , then you get 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the query:

```
echo $sql;
```

And check the values of $start and $limit that goes into it.